# Error trying to save the schema: "The complexType 'uuid:7a55541b-9084-4b21-9351-06b3d1c0b4f2:Content' has already been declared."

Tags: 2013, schema

I'm creating a Metadata Schema and when I try to add a new field with a Embedded Schema I get the next error: 
"The complexType 'uuid:7a55541b-9084-4b21-9351-06b3d1c0b4f2:Content' has already been declared."

The Embedded Schema is the following: 
[image]

And I'm trying to add it in:

[image]

Con someone help me?
Thank you,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because you have 2 embedded schemas in the same schema, and did not change the Root Element name for either.

More detail on this is available on [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3710/33).

The short story is that you can fix this by changing the Root Element Name of your embeddable schemas to something else than "Content". You may have to change the schema type to Content first before changing the Root Element name, then change it back to Embeddable Schema.

Comment: I think the same thing happens with any two embeddable schemas in the same content schema which happen to have the same root element name. It doesn't have to be 'Content'.